# Create Trigger, Compilation with errors

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger but it failed, and gives no logs just message : "ORA-24344 : succes with compilcation error"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJVCx.png)

Comment: Please don't post links of images, use formatted text for your code.

Comment: Please add code directly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I can't view images. But - do as the following example shows:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_test
  2    before insert on emp
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    select * from dual;
  6  end;
  7  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

SQL> col text format a80
SQL> select text from user_errors where name = 'TRG_BI_TEST';

TEXT
---------------------------------------------------------------------
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

SQL>
```

In other words, query `USER_ERRORS`

Answer (score 0):

> ORA-24344 : success with compilation error

This messages means you managed to create the trigger object but the code is invalid and cannot be executed. Most IDEs will display compilation errors automatically, but if you're not using such a tool then you need to query USER_ERRORS. So that would be

```
select * from user_errors
where name = 'UPDATE_TRIGGER'
```

In this case your trigger won't compile because there is **no code** between the BEGIN and END statements. That is not valid PL/SQL.

If for some reason you want to build a stub trigger you need to put something in the body. NULL will do:

```
begin
  null;
end;
```